# google-spreadsheet: IMPORTHTML, IMPORTXML не видит IP-adress(192.168.0.102)

Tags: google-spreadsheet

мне надо вытащить данные с локальной веб страницы(ESP8266) в таблицу гугл. Формула

```
=IMPORTHTML("http://192.168.0.102";"list";1)
```

выдает ошибку:

> Ссылка http://192.168.0.102 недействительна.

IMPORTXML - аналогично. Пробовал адрес роутера 192.168.0.1 - тоже самое.

Как решить эту проблему?

Comment: таблицы гугла пытаются получить доступ к вашему "серверу", но он в локальной сети. Ищите, как пробросить 80 порт на сервере через роутер и указывайте внешний адрес Вашего роутера (а Вы указали внутренний)

Comment: Пробросил порт, доступ из внешки есть, Но все  равно не работает: Ссылка http://hello.....ddns.net недействительна

Comment: я с гуглом согласен - адрес с несколькими точками подряд действительно недействительный.

Comment: это я реальный адрес затер, "доступ из внешки есть". Пробовал 
Quantool - Html парсер с виджетом и уведомлениями для андроид тоже не забирает данные с этих веб страниц.

Comment: К сожалению, это никак не проверить. Но попробуйте посмотреть в логи веб сервера. Возможно, там будет зацепка

Comment: Вот ответ автора программы, немного прояснил суть: Моя программа смотрит исходный код страницы и парсит данные оттуда. В вашем случае в исходном коде страницы значение температуры датчика всегда равно 0. А страница обновляется каким-то скриптом, видимо. Вам нужно как-то сделать так, чтобы в исходном коде веб страницы выводилось именно текущее значение.

Comment: Тему можно закрыть. Мы пойдем другим путем... :)